# HIbernate - Table Update - Allow one request at a time to update

Tags: hibernate

We have an application with handle multiple request but DB table should be updated by one request at a time. We are connected to DB through Hibernate. How can we achieve this?
Thank You in advance.

Comment: You have to use the JDBC isolation level TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE. But why do you want to do that? What's your use case?

Comment: We want to do allow a single user to update the table at a given point of time. If multiple users request to update the table then one request has to update the table to maintain data consistency.

Comment: But that's what transactions are for. They provide isolation. Tell me more about what exactly you want to do

Comment: Thanks Simon. Can you provide me any link for learning hibernate?

Comment: Please consider below table and if one request is updating area1(4 rows) then other requests should not be able perform any operatiosns for area1(4 rows) but can perform operatiosns on area2. If the above scenario is not achievable then if one request is updating area1 then all other requests should be blocked or operations should be performed in a queue instead of throwing error.                                              Area Sub Area
area1 met1
area1 met2
area1 met3
area1 met4
area2 met1
area2 met2
area2 met3
area2 met4